# Add a parameter to a div within a droppable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add a parameter to a div once its dropped onto a droppable.
Is there a method which resembles addParameter below which can add the paramter ?

```
    $( ".placeHolder" ).droppable({ drop: function( event, ui ) 
            { 
       "#"+this.id.addParameter(myParam="testParam");
}
```

Comment: What is the parameter supposed to do?

Comment: @chucktator its just a string parameter which I access from using the div ID at a later point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean setting the attribute to the draggable element, then you can use:

```
$(".placeHolder").droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        ui.draggable.attr("myParam", "testParam");
    }
});
```

Otherwise, just use `ui.draggable` as a jQuery object of the draggable element.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `.attr()` function. To set the attribute use

```
$(this).attr('my_attribute', 'my_value');
```

and to get it use

```
$(this).attr('my_attribute');
```